# Pares de elementos en numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Elemento de lista

Tengo los siguientes vectores:

```py
vector1 = [1,2,3]
vector2 = [4,5,6]
```

Tendría que combinarlos de tal manera que obtuviera un tercer vector/lista cuyo output fuera así:

```py
vector3 = [(1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6)]
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: `combinacion = [(x, y) for x in vector1 for y in vector2]`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias !!!!